# How to use logging with Django?

Tags: django, database, logging, admin

I try to log variables to the console, but it doesn't show anything. Each competitor is assigned to a group via Foreign Key. I want to log in the list of "flname" within each group. For example, one of the Foreign key is "blue". How do I log in all of the "flname" within that group? Any suggestion?
Thanks,

```
admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Group, Competitors
import logging

class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ("flname", "Weight", "rank", "Group_FK", "point")
  def __str__(self):
     return self.Group_FK
admin.site.unregister(Competitors)
admin.site.register(Competitors, MemberAdmin)

class GroupCompetitorInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Competitors
   readonly_fields = ('flname', 'Weight', 'rank',)
   extra = 0

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [GroupCompetitorInline]

admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)


def logging(request):
    flnames = Competitors.objects.filter(Group_FK=Group.objects.get(pk='___').values_list('flname', flat=True))
    logging.warning('flnames')
```

settings.py

```
FORMATTERS = (
    {
        "verbose": {
            "format": "{levelname} {asctime:s} {threadName} {thread:d} {module} {filename} {lineno:d} {name} {funcName} {process:d} {message}",
            "style": "{",
        },
        "simple": {
            "format": "{levelname} {asctime:s} {module} {filename} {lineno:d} {funcName} {message}",
            "style": "{",
        },
    },
)


HANDLERS = {
    "console_handler": {
        "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        "formatter": "simple",
    },
    "my_handler": {
        "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
        "filename": f"{BASE_DIR}/logs/blogthedata.log",
        "mode": "a",
        "encoding": "utf-8",
        "formatter": "simple",
        "backupCount": 5,
        "maxBytes": 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
    },
    "my_handler_detailed": {
        "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
        "filename": f"{BASE_DIR}/logs/blogthedata_detailed.log",
        "mode": "a",
        "formatter": "verbose",
        "backupCount": 5,
        "maxBytes": 1024 * 1024 * 5,  # 5 MB
    },
}

LOGGERS = (
    {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console_handler", "my_handler_detailed"],
            "level": "INFO",
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["my_handler"],
            "level": "WARNING",
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },
)


LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
        },
    },
    "root": {
        "handlers": ["console"],
        "level": "WARNING",
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": os.getenv("DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL", "INFO"),
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: `logging` is the name of the python logger modul. You should NOT redefine a function with the same name (`def logging(...`).